# Get-ADUser output manipulation

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I run the following against my client's AD... It produces what appears to be CSV.

```
$members=Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "my ad group" -Recursive | % {Get-ADUser -Identity $_.distinguishedName -Properties * | ? {$_.enabled -eq $true} | select-object emailaddress}

$members

emailaddress
------------
john.bob@org.com
pete.smith@org.com
```

however, trying search in this variable does not work so well. The best I can do is this

```
$members -like "@{emailaddress=john.bob@org.com}"
@{emailaddress=john.bob@org.com}
```

But I would like to do this:

```
$members -like "john.bob@org.com"
john.bob@org.com
```

I would like the initial command to produce a simpler array, so that the last '-like' syntax works. How to do this?

Comment: Change `select-object emailaddress` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty emailaddress`

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Please post a formal answer, I will accept this.